# Read a 3d Array from File

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a file with the following values:

```
1 2
3 4

11 12
13 14
```

and I want to read them as a numpy 2x2x2 array. The standard command `np.loadtxt('testfile')` reads them in as lots of vectors ignoring the spaces (4x1x8). I suppose I could iterate over them and stack them together in the right way, but my actual data files are pretty large and would rather not have too many while loops if possible. Is there a nice way to do this within the numpy system?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Reshape is your friend

Answer (score 8):

Use [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.loadtxt('testfile')
>>> a
array([[  1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.],
       [ 11.,  12.],
       [ 13.,  14.]])
>>> a.reshape((2, 2, 2))
array([[[  1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.]],

       [[ 11.,  12.],
        [ 13.,  14.]]])
```

Comment: In cases where axes order doesn't get right, `numpy.rollaxis` and `numpy.swapaxes` can do interesting stuff...